# get columns not found error when assigning columns using groupby method and created columns by pandas

Tags: pandas

**df_w**

```
date         ts_code    vol
0   2021/5/9    300671.SZ   194865.78
1   2021/5/9    603026.SH   148529.63
2   2021/5/16   300671.SZ   484864.38
3   2021/5/16   603026.SH   335544.74
4   2021/5/23   300671.SZ   378664.39
5   2021/5/23   603026.SH   324002.13
6   2021/5/30   300671.SZ   477692.86
7   2021/5/30   603026.SH   255070.64
8   2021/6/6    300671.SZ   552003.44
9   2021/6/6    603026.SH   512698.37
10  2021/6/13   300671.SZ   595403.53
11  2021/6/13   603026.SH   582774.23
12  2021/6/20   300671.SZ   427875.49
13  2021/6/20   603026.SH   496716.51
14  2021/6/27   300671.SZ   551570.55
15  2021/6/27   603026.SH   388483.83
16  2021/7/4    300671.SZ   736659.9
17  2021/7/4    603026.SH   502127.57
18  2021/7/11   300671.SZ   1095915.74
19  2021/7/11   603026.SH   663312.72
20  2021/7/18   300671.SZ   874362.11
21  2021/7/18   603026.SH   845797.04
22  2021/7/25   300671.SZ   607797.58
23  2021/7/25   603026.SH   470974.62
```

I create `ma50wvol` columns and want to assign `l_ma50w_vol` column like below, but get `KeyError: 'Column not found: ma50w_vol'`

```
df_w=df_w.assign(
            ma50wvol=df_w.groupby('ts_code')['vol'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(50,1).mean()),
            l_ma50w_vol=lambda x:x.groupby('ts_code')['ma50w_vol'].shift(1),
            )
```

It's strange that it works when using lambda if assigning columns by created columns, but if using groupby it failed. Hope to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check your column name it should be `ma50wvol`

```
df_w = df_w.assign(
    ma50wvol=df_w.groupby('ts_code')['vol'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(50,1).mean()),
    l_ma50w_vol=lambda x:x.groupby('ts_code')['ma50wvol'].shift(1)
)
```